# Block is rendered, but toHtml() function is not called

Tags: magento2.3, layout, developer-mode, magento-2-commerce, lazyload

Using Magento Commerce 2.3.5-p2.

I'm changing the template of the layered navigation from a custom module like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.navigation.renderer"
                                template="Vendor_Module::layer/filter.phtml"/>
```

This works correctly.

I am displaying images for some filters, and I want to have them lazy-loaded with Magefan_Lazyload.

The module has a plugin in `frontend/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
        <plugin name="magefan_lazyload_lock"
                type="Magefan\LazyLoad\Plugin\BlockPlugin" sortOrder="1000"/>
    </type>
```

In my opinion, this should work for all blocks that extend `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`, so for example for all `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` blocks.

It works for some `Template`-blocks, but it doesn't work for some other blocks, such as `catalog.leftnav`, or the one I am changing above.

I also added debug code to `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::toHtml()`, and it seems that this method is never called for my block. Also, I don't think the `toHtml()` method is overwritten somewhere.

Any tips?

I am running in developer mode. Strange enough, it works different in production mode - `catalog.leftnav` is recognized, but still not `catalog.navigation.renderer`.

I also tried changing the plugin's `sortOrder` to 1, this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check the [Magento 2 Lazy Load](https://magefan.com/magento-2-image-lazy-load-extension) extension documentation [here](https://magefan.com/magento-2-image-lazy-load-extension/configuration).

The extension has an option to define images in what blocks need to be lazy-loaded - "Lazy Load Blocks" option where you need to define one of these:

1. block name in the layout
2. block class name, e.g.:
   MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Someblock\Interceptor
3. block .phtml template name, e.g.:
   MyCompany_MyModule::folder/template.phtml

You can check how it works here on [github](https://github.com/magefan/module-lazyload/blob/master/Plugin/BlockPlugin.php#L108) - "isEnabled" method.

If you want to enable lazy loading for some specific cms block or page, or other WYSIWYG content, you need to add this comment somewhere in the content:

```
<!-- MAGEFAN_LAZY_LOAD -->
```

Comment: I already did all of that. Configuration is fine, and I am not a first time user of that module ;) also, as I pointed more, production mode „hits“ some more blocks than developer mode, but still not all of them. The blocks I mentioned are not even running through isEnabled(), this is what I find weird.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, do you use varnish?

Comment: Not on my local machine; I use default Magento2 FPC, but have it disabled for development, and cleaning/flushing the cache has no effect on the blocks that run through isEnabled()